# How to prevent PC's system resume

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bios, battery-life, smart

Here's my situation:

I left my laptop ON last night and got fully discharged its battery.
It has already a hard drive faults.  Only a week since the `SMART` warning always appearing whenever I boot it.  But I am quite sure that my hard disk nor the boot warning does do a thing that prevents it from starting the OS because I couldn't even access the `BIOS` setup and even boot any cd/dvd from it. It just get stock on the screen where the `SMART` warning has been displayed and pressing any keys doesn't do anything, but my keyboard is fine, as when I press many keys, the BIOS is complaining about it, getting slower to load, and beeps when I press `esc` key.  I do a lot of key combination but none of them bypass on that screen(even F1 as the warning says to continue). I think this is some kind of looping over and over again from that kind of situation where it cannot decide where to go. Lets assume that my hard disk is healthy and SMART warnings does the real thing here, now, how do I prevent system from resuming its last session? Any key combinations or some resetting on hardwares? Don't suggest any booting from cds because it will never work in my situation.

**EDIT**

Thank you guys for your time reading this. I appreciate all of your answers and comments. My problem is **solved** now. I hope my laptop's hard drive would live more than expected. Thanks again :)

Comment: Try unplugging it and taking the battery out then leaving it for a while before putting it back in again.

Comment: I already did it :(

Comment: If you pulled the battery and left it unplugged then its not resuming anymore. You have a hard drive problem. Boot to your windows disk and run chkdsk /r from the recovery console.

Comment: I could not get any far than the `SMART` screen warning. Removing and bringing the battery back(the external/big one) cannot prevent it from resuming on its last session.

Comment: Please post the solution as an Answer and mark it as the answer so others can see what worked. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume the possibility that the hard drive could be "crashed" and is preventing the boot process from proceeding.

The computer may be trying to access the hard drive and the hard drive is not responding, and the computer is waiting for it.  The drive is probably reporting that it is not in a "Ready" state.  The computer "knows" the drive is attached, and the computer thinks the drive is not ready, like it is not running at an operational speed yet, or it is not done with internal diagnostics.  The computer could wait for a very long time. If the state of the signals from the drive is not as expected by the programs in the BIOS, it could get "confused" and become "locked-up".

Try this: Remove the hard drive and then try to boot-up the laptop. See if you are able to get past the point you are at now, and see if you can get in to see the BIOS settings.  If you are able to get along further, it pretty much confirms that the hard drive is now bad.

In certian cases, depending on age, usage, temperature, etc... you may get longer, but in my experience, when the SMART warning has appeared, you may only have a week of normal use, or less before the drive actually fails. I have had 2 hard drives fail within a week of the SMART warning, and a third drive that lasted considerably longer... a little over a month.  That is only from my experience, I don't know what the overall "average" might be.

Comment: yey! this one works!! thanks!! I removed the hard drive during the boot time then it goes to the screen where I can choose whether to resume the system or boot normally.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the first answer, there are two 'batteries' in your laptop. One is the big one you clip out, the other is hidden under your keyboard most likely and stores information when the laptop isn't connected to any power. Try removing them both for about 10-15 minutes and trying again. There should be instructions to remove your CMOS battery on Google when you search for that with your laptop type included.

Comment: Okay, I will comeback here tomorrow to see if I can fix it that way.